# ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

Tengo problemas al ejecutar este código:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('titulo', 'texto',)
```

Y me sale este error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Utilizo python 3.7 y django 2.2

Comment: parece un error relacionado al tema de importacion relativa y absoluta

Comment: podrías anexar el arbol de directorios de tu proyecto

Comment: genial y como podria hacerlo soy nuevo lo sigo desde un curso pero  se me presente este error

Comment: Fabrizzio, me suena a que estás tratando de ejecutar ese script directamente. Lo que tienes que hacer es usar `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: cesar si lo eh ejecutado python manage.py runserver pero tengo ese error en  views.py forms.py urls.py

Comment: tambien al ejecutar en el servidor obtengo este error 127.0.0.1/8000

Comment: TypeError en /
post_list () falta 1 argumento posicional requerido: 'pk'

Comment: TypeError - quiere decir que tienes un error sintáctico en este caso que la funcion post_list le hace falta un argumento que declaraste como 'pk'

Comment: si si buenisimo mas o menos lo tengo  no lo puedo anexar es demasiado largo lo hice con el comando tree